# How to make CircleCI call npm install on two places?

Tags: circleci

I have just started working with CircleCI so I don't know whether this is too obvious.

Problem is, that I have react website and react native project in one folder. React website uses `project/package.json` and `project/node_modules`, while React Native project uses `project/nativeApp/package.json` and `project/nativeApp/node_modules`.

To make both run and test correctly, I need to `npm install` in both locations. How do I tell CircleCI to do that?